# WorksheetFunction.CountA not returning correct value

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is iterate through a range containing worksheet names, and if the cell is not empty then add the result of `CountA` function to the count variable.

So the count variable should be equal to number of non-blank cells in range `B9:B28` on the worksheets I'm iterating through, but strangely the value is equal to the number of non empty cells in the range I'm going through (`sheet1!d5:d24`).

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code I am using:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d5:d24").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountA(c & "!b9:b28")
    End If
Next
```

I tried an alternative method to loop through second range and if the cells are not empty, then increment the variable by 1 but that's giving a *Run time error 13 type mismatch* error. This is what I am doing now:

```
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d5:d24")
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        For Each c2 In Worksheets(c).Range("b9:b28")
            If Not IsEmpty(c2) Then
                'count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountA(c & "!b9:b28")
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Please help me out. Thanks a lot in advance to all those who take out time to reply.

Comment: I think you need to provide `.CountA` with a range object and not a string. Try `.CountA(Worksheets(c).Range("B9:B28"))`

Comment: You use cell (as range object) and try to add address notation to it. Surely that wont work. Follow @PeterAlbert suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. I tried @Peter Albert's solution but it threw a type mismatch error. I provided string because I thought the functions work the same in VBA as in Excel.

Comment: Finally got it.Based on @PeterL.'s reply I used `c.Value` and it worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @AmitKumarJha submit it as your own answer to avoid further efforts from community. You'll be able to accept it in a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @Peter Albert and @Peter L. 's comments, finally got it working. The correct code is:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d5:d24").Cells
If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
    count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountA(c.Value & "!b9:b28")
End If
Next
```

Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub CountColBForColD()
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Long   'row counter
Dim rngB As Range
Dim rngD As Range
Dim lookSheet As Worksheet

Set rngD = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:D24")
Set rngB = Range("B9:B28")
r = 1

For Each c In rngD
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        On Error GoTo InvalidSheetName
        Set lookSheet = Sheets(rngB(r).Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Count = Count + WorksheetFunction.CountA( _
            lookSheet.Range(rngB.Address))
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Count
            r = r + 1
    End If
NxtC:
Next

Exit Sub

InvalidSheetName:
Err.Clear
MsgBox "Sheet named in  " & rngB(r).Address & " does not exist.", vbInformation
Resume NxtC

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @David Zemens but I also got it working. Really thanks for churning out the sub so quickly.